# Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript

i try to make othello with javascript, and trying to give user hint by changing the tile color
but everytime user click and call function to find the proper place to put the disk
when it trigger function `ifgreen()` i got error

> Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

but when i `console.log` the class , i can see the actual div class and it change the color from green to greenwhite
whats wrong with my code?

is this because i add "`<div class='green "+i+j+"' onclick='clickfunc("+i+","+j+");'></div>`" when window load?

```
var t = 0;

function ifgreen(i, j) {
  var butu = "'green " + i + j + "'";
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName(butu); //error
  y[0].classList.toggle("greenwhite"); //error
  y[0].classList.toggle("green");

}


function find() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      if (ban[i][j] == player) {
        hint(i, j);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

function when user click one of the green pieces

```
function clickfunc(i, j) {
  console.log(i, j);
  find();
  if (ban[i][j] === 0 && player === 1 && checkblack(i, j, 1, 1) >= 1) {
    console.log(checkblack(i, j, 2));
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Black turn";
    ban[i][j] = 1;
    player = 2;
    checkk(i, j);

    a();
  }
}
```

function to draw the othello table

```
function a() {
  document.getElementById("bann").innerHTML = "";

  for (i = 0; i < ban.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ban[i].length; j++) {

      if (ban[i][j] === 0)
        document.getElementById("bann").innerHTML += "<div class = 'green "+i+j+"' onclick = 'clickfunc("+i+","+j+");' > < /div>";
      else if (ban[i][j] === 1)
        document.getElementById("bann").innerHTML += "<div class = 'banwhite "+i+j+"' onclick = 'clickfunc("+i+","+j+");' > < /div>";
      else if (ban[i][j] === 2)
        document.getElementById("bann").innerHTML += "<div class = 'banblack "+i+j+"' onclick = 'clickfunc("+i+","+j+");' > < /div>";
    }

    document.getElementById("bann").innerHTML += "<br>";
  }

}


window.onload = a();
```

this is the entire program
https://jsfiddle.net/emoawj4v/

Comment: `window.onload=a();` is wrong, you are saying call `a` and assign what it returns to onload. Drop the `()`

Comment: The class "selector" stored in `butu` is incorrect

Comment: @epascarello ok but it produced the same result, with or without() ?

Comment: @Andreas why it is incorrect?

Comment: className's don't have spaces in them.  But what some people do, is replace a space with an underscore, so you could maybe do `green_00`, `green_01` etc.

Comment: @Keith That's not the problem here, because that's the way how `.getElementsByClassName()` expects a list of classes to look for.

Comment: Your fiddle does not run because the script is included inside of window.onload block by the way you have it set up and those global functions are no longer global. ANd you clasname selector is wrong with the quotes. You only quote strings, not variables.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, was assuming it's single classes,..  Seems strange creating a class called `00,01,02` etc.  But if that's what the OP is doing..

Comment: @epascarello yeah the fiddle is not working, do i need to delete the window.onload? and just call a(); in the fiddle?

Comment: o, fiddle is set up to run onload. You have to change the fiddle settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> let i=1
> let j=2
> "'green "+i+j+"'"
"'green 12'"
```

So the class would have to be called literally `'green 12'`, including the `'` quotes (eg. `<div class="'green 12'"></div>`). Whis is not what you have in your `a` function, obviously. The `getElementsByClassName` function can't find any element with these class names and returns an empty *HTMLCollection* as a result (`y[0]` is hence `undefined` and this is where your error message comes from).

So, dropping `'` should do the trick:

```
> "green "+i+j
'green 12'
```

in your code:

```
var butu = "green " + i + j; // => eg. "green 12"
var y = document.getElementsByClassName(butu)
```

> By the way, class names can't have spaces – `"green 12"`  are in fact
>   two classes (`green` and `12`). If you want to compose a single class
>   name, it's common to use dashes in place of spaces (eg. `green-12`).

And, as @epascarello noted, you're supposed to attach a function reference to `onload` (and other events), not it's result.

So `window.onload = a()` ("run `a` and assign it's result to `window.onload`") should really be just `window.onload = a` ("run `a` when `window.onload`" happens).

Comment: _"The getElementsByClassName function can't find an element with this class name and returns undefined"_ That's wrong. [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-getelementsbyclassname) **always** returns a `HTMLCollection`